# Saving Java objects into files

Tags: java, serialization, file-io, save

I have the following class in Java. I would like to be able to save it into a common file format that would be able to moved across different pc's. I know about object serialization but I was wondering what are my other options and what are their respective pros and cons. Thanks! Like for example a serialized file is not human readable and therefore a con.

```
public class NervousSystem {
    private CentralNervousSystem CNS;
    private PeripheralNervousSystem PNS;

    public NervousSystem(Neocortex neocortex, LateralGeniculateNucleus LGN, Retina retina) {
        this.CNS = new CentralNervousSystem(neocortex, LGN);
        this.PNS = new PeripheralNervousSystem(retina);
    }

    public CentralNervousSystem getCNS() {
        return this.CNS;
    }

    public PeripheralNervousSystem getPNS() {
        return this.PNS;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could take a look at [Java Architecture for XML Binding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Json, use  [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)...

It supports arbitrarily complex objects and you don't need setters or getters. Gson just figures it all out.

**Convert to JSON**

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String myObjectJson = gson.toJson( myObj);
println myObjectJson
```

**Convert from JSON**

```
MyObj obj = gson.fromJson(myObjectJson, MyObj.class)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! But now that it's a string should I save it into a text file or something?

Comment: You can do whatever you want, serialize to file as json, it will be portable and readable, in that form.

Answer (score 8):

You can serialize the objects to [JSON](http://www.json.org/) using e.g. [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/), which will greatly improve their human readability

Answer (score 4):

You can generate a XML of your javabean using the `java.beans.XMLEncoder`.
Check one tutorial [here](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-convert-a-javabean-to-an-xml-string-using-xmlencoder.html).

Example of one xml generated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<java version="1.7.0_10" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder">
 <object class="com.test.MyBean">
  <void property="myBoolean">
   <boolean>true</boolean>
  </void>
  <void property="myString">
   <string>xml is cool</string>
  </void>
  <void property="myVector">
   <object class="java.util.Vector">
    <void method="add">
     <string>one</string>
    </void>
    <void method="add">
     <string>two</string>
    </void>
    <void method="add">
     <string>three</string>
    </void>
   </object>
  </void>
 </object>
</java>
```

Answer (score 1):

JAXB marshalls and unmarshalls objects according to annotations. The annotations allow you to:

- Control the serialization format.
- Insulate your serialization format from some refactorings of your code.
- Identify fields to be excluded from serialization.

Here's an [Oracle tutorial on JAXB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/).

For example, an annotated class might look like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="foo")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Foo {

    @XmlTransient
    private String m_temp; 

    @XmlAttribute(name="fieldA")
    private String fieldA;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [xstream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html), a simple and commonly used Java XML serialization library. In a nutshell it looks like this (example nicked from the xstream website):

```
public class Person {
  private String firstname;
  private String lastname;
  private PhoneNumber phone;
  private PhoneNumber fax;
  // getters & setters
}

public class PhoneNumber {
  private int code;
  private String number;
  // getters & setters
}

XStream xstream = new XStream();
Person joe = new Person("Joe", "Walnes");
joe.setPhone(new PhoneNumber(123, "1234-456"));
joe.setFax(new PhoneNumber(123, "9999-999"));
String xml = xstream.toXML(joe);
```

The XML contents look like this:

```
<mypackage.Person>
  <firstname>Joe</firstname>
  <lastname>Walnes</lastname>
  <phone>
    <code>123</code>
    <number>1234-456</number>
  </phone>
  <fax>
    <code>123</code>
    <number>9999-999</number>
  </fax>
</mypackage.Person>
```

This is the simplest example, you can do a lot of customizations for more complex situations.